# Trying to write a custom validator for "alpha" with formvalidator.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm using the formvalidator.net jQuery plugin and trying to write a custom validator that will not accept numeric input (the "alphanumeric" type allows numbers). I wrote the function below but am not sure what to pass for the `$el, config, language, $form` arguments, and I don't understand the documentation, which is here: http://formvalidator.net/#custom-validators

The documentation explains the arguments, but I don't know how to format them correctly; I'm brand new to jQuery and generally new to Javascript. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code, thanks for your help!

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
  name : 'non-numeric',
  validatorFunction : function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {

    var numericRe = /[0-9]/;
    return !numericRe.test(value);

  },
  errorMessage : 'Please enter a valid name (no numbers)',
  errorMessageKey: 'badContainsNumber'
});                 

$.validate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is reference the `name` property in your form:

```
<input type="text" data-validation="non-numeric" />
```

The `value`, `$el`, `config`, `language`, and `$form` parameters are automatically passed to the `validatorFunction` callback function.  They are for your convenience (`value` is the value,`$el` is the input,  not sure about `config` and `language` without reading the documentation, and `$form` is the form).

Currently your custom validator will allow anything as long as it doesn't have number (so `!@#` validates, which isn't "alpha").  If you want [pure "alpha"](http://regex101.com/r/gB8kJ0), use a function like this:

```
function(value, $el, config, language, $form) {
    return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}
```

The `^` and `$` will anchor your match to the beginning/end of the string and `i` makes it case-insensitive.  Note that this will look for 1+ letter, if you want the string to be valid if empty you will need 0+ characters: `[a-z]*`.

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why this wasn't working before since I put this EXACT code into my script and it wouldn't validate. I must have changed something without realizing it. Thanks for explaining parameters.